# Loading and displaying a 16 (12) bit grayscale png into a PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, winforms, png, grayscale

I'm using a framework for some camera hardware called IDS Peak and we are receiving 16 bit grayscale images back from the framework, the framework itself can write the files to disk as PNGs and that's all good and well, but how do I display them in a `PictureBox` in Winforms?

Windows Bitmap does not support 16 bit grayscale so the following code throws a 'Parameter is not valid.' System.ArgumentException

```
var image = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, iplImg.Data());
```

`iplImg.Data()` here is an IntPtr to the bespoke Image format of the framework.

Considering Windows Bitmap does not support the format, and I can write the files using the framework to PNGs, how can I do one of the following:

1. Convert to a different object type other than `Bitmap` to display directly in Winforms without reading from the files.
2. Load the 16-bit grayscale PNG files into the `PictureBox` control (or any other control type, it doesn't have to be a `PictureBox`).

(1) is preferable as it doesn't require file IO but if (2) is the only possibility that's completely fine as I need to both save and display them anyway but (1) only requires a write operation and not a secondary read.

*The files before writing to disc are actually monochrome with 12 bits per pixel, packed.*

Comment: Does your monitor support this?

Comment: 100% normal monitor is the problem. The images are being displayed fine in other image editing programs like windows image editor and Irfanview, if I use `PictureBox.Load()` it does load them from disk fine.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to display 16-bit images, for example by hosting a wpf control in winforms, you probably want to apply a windowing function to reduce the image to 8 bit before display.

So lets use unsafe code and pointers for speed:

```
            var bitmapData = myBitmap.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                myBitmap.PixelFormat);

            try
            {
                 var ptr= (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
                 var stride = bitmapData.Stride;
                 var width = bitmapData.Width;
                 var height= bitmapData.Height;
                 // Conversion Code
            }
            finally
            {
                myBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }
```

or using wpf image classes, that generally have better 16-bit support:

```
var myBitmap= new WriteableBitmap(new BitmapImage(new Uri("myBitmap.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));
writeableBitmap.Lock();
try{
     var ptr = (byte*)myBitmap.BackBuffer;
     ...
}
finally
{
      myBitmap.Unlock();
}
```

To loop over all the pixels you would use a double loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    var row = (ushort*)(ptr+ y * stride);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        var pixelValue = row[x];
        // Scaling code
    }
}
```

And to scale the value you could use a linear scaling between the min and max values to the 0-255 range of a byte

```
var slope = (byte.MaxValue + 1f) / (maxUshortValyue - minUshortValue);
var scaled = (int)(((pixelValue + 0.5f - minUshortValue) * slope)) ;
scaled = scaled > byte.MaxValue ? byte.MaxValue: scaled;
scaled = scaled < 0 ? 0: scaled;
var byteValue = (byte)scaled;
```

The `maxUshortValyue` / `minUshortValue` would either be computed from the max/min value of the image, or configured by the user. You would also need to create a target image in order to write down the result into a target 8-bit grayscale bitmap to be displayed, or write down the same value for each color channel in a color image.

Comment: `// Conversion Code` here is the code from my example that throws an error? And How could I get the min max values from the image? Sorry images are probably the one part of programming I know the least about. I'm just finding it hard to put all three of these together.

Comment: @JayCroghan  Added an example on how to load images with wpf, you could also use some third party library to load images. The example shows how to iterate over all pixels, to get the min/max just do: `maxValue = Math.Max(pixelValue, maxValue)`  for all pixels.

Comment: I'm getting `System.AccessViolationException` on pixels well within the bounds of the image.

Comment: Sorry previous comment meant to say on `var pixelValue = row[x]`

Comment: Sorry for bombarding with comments, when I asked about min/max I meant `maxUshortValue` and `minUshortValue`

Comment: @JayCroghan start by double checking that your bitmap actually have 2 bytes per pixel, that would be the most likely reason for an AccesViolation. To get the min/max values you first do one loop over all the pixels, then another to do the scaling.

Comment: the framework gives me back width, height and stride and stride is definitely width * 2 so that's fine. I changed it to use the stride etc given back to me from the framework instead and the access violation no longer happens. Can I set `row[x]` and it will update the location at the pointer originally referenced or do I need to do some `Marshal` writing? I still can't visualise the two loops you're speaking about. Maybe it's just because it's Friday night and my head is melted with this already.

Comment: @JayCroghan Yes, you can set the value at the pointer, but as mentioned in the answer, you should probably write the scaled pixel values to a new bitmap